# cannot access the .dll file because it's being used by another process?

Tags: c#, asp.net

OK, this is getting very annoying. Whenever i run any `.aspx` file, i sometimes get these errors:
`Error  11  Could not copy "obj\Debug\SMC.dll" to "bin\SMC.dll". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.

Error   12  Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\SMC.dll" to "bin\SMC.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\SMC.dll' because it is being used by another process.`

I delete the files in `bin` and `obj` folder, *clean* the solution and *build* it again, the errors go for a bit and then when i run the code they appear again. I have no clue as to what to do and what's the reason. They don't occur on any specific file. Can be on any of them.

P.S: I made the project in VS 2013 Express originally. Due to my need to use Crystal reports, i started using VS2012. And i have them both installed still.

Is the code relevent here? please let me know and i will post the code of any `.aspx` file. 
Thanks!

Comment: are you stop express server also?

Comment: are you talking about IIS Express? if yes, then no i don't stop that. it runs whenever i run my code.

Comment: when you run your project - msvs run debug server: IIS Express or something like, so this a process that can use application dll

Comment: so what do you recommend? Do i have to keep deleting the files from the said folders re-bulding the soultion over and over? or is there a way to stop that.

Comment: if you have this error you can stop express server and re-run or rebuild

Comment: alright, but will it stop the errors from reoccuring for good or is it a temporary solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71982/discussion-between-grundy-and-sana-qureshi).

Comment: What was the solution to this issue? I am stuck and can't seem to solve it either.