# Invalid column name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Ok, i have tried for hours and can't see what's wrong with the code. (i have gone code blind probably, but that's what happens when you have been coding for over 24 hours non stop :D). It's a very small code. I simply have to select some columns and show them in a gridview. I made my query, and when i run it, i am getting: `Invalid column name Donor`

C# code:

```
string str = "SELECT BBID, Name, ContactNum, Email, Gender, BloodGroup, Category, Address FROM Bloodbank WHERE (Category = N'Donor')";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adp.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
```

My database table:

```
SELECT [BBID]
  ,[Name]
  ,[ContactNum]
  ,[Email]
  ,[Gender]
  ,[BloodGroup]
  ,[Category]
  ,[Address]
```

FROM [SMC].[dbo].[Bloodbank]

In `Category`, you can choose `Donor` or `Reciever` through a `DropDownList`.
I am sure it will be some stupid mistake i am making but i am totally at loss here. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**P.S:** This query works perfectly in the SSMS.

Comment: check your connection string, database name, and table properly.

Comment: i have, multiple times.

Comment: Use parametrtized queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you made sure that your DDL is putting quotes around the value that is selected? It sounds like the query is using "Category = Donor" (no single quotes) instead of "Category = N'Donor'"

Comment: yes i have but then i am having issues with the .dll file. Please refer to the [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794087/cannot-access-the-dll-file-because-its-being-used-by-another-process). I have tried cleaning the solution and rebuilding it number of times ( i have to do it each time .dll error occurs) but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You should use SqlParameter with your code as shown in following code snippet. I assume that DataType of Category field is NvarChar(10). It will give some flexibility to your code in future.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=CatalogName;Integrated Security=True");            
        string str = "SELECT [BBID], [Name], [ContactNum], [Email], [Gender], [BloodGroup], [Category], [Address] FROM [Bloodbank] WHERE ([Category] = @Category)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("Category", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        param.Value = "Donor";
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adp.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
```